# Angular Library "includePaths" alternative

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am trying to build a angular 11 library with some wrapper components around Syncfusion's EJ2.
I am trying to import scss files from their node_modules directive, and [as per their documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/common/how-to/sass/), to avoid SCSS compilation issues and to map the SCSS file path it's required to add  "`node_modules/@syncfusion"` to the `"includePaths"` property of the `"stylePreprocessorOptions"` in the angular.json config file.

Being in angular library however, I do not have such property. **What would be the equivalent or a way to achieve the same result?**

**ALREADY TRIED**

- [This](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11249) issue suggests adding the entry in the "styleIncludePaths" of the ng-package.json file. This however is not working (the import fails as the file is not found)

Answer (score 3):

We have created a sample angular library application for your reference that you can download from the below link.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/workspace1508444094

“ng-package.json” configuration:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/lib",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "styleIncludePaths": [“../../node_modules/@syncfusion”]
  }
}
```

“lib.component.scss”:

```
@import '~@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons/styles/material.scss';
```

1. Download the sample
2. Run the “npm install” command in root directory.
3. Build the library and app using “ npm run build”
4. Serve the application with lib component using “ npm run start”.